# How can I read ListView Column Headers and their values?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, columnheader

I've been trying to find out a way to read data from the selected `ListView` row and display each value in their respected `TextBox` for easy editing.

The first and easiest way would be something like this:

```
ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];

buyCount_txtBox.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
buyPrice_txtBox.Text = item.SubItems[2].Text;
sellPrice_txtBox.Text = item.SubItems[3].Text;
```

There is nothing wrong with that code but I have around 40 or more `TextBoxes` that should display data. Coding all 40 or so would become very tedious.

The solution I've come up with, is to get all `TextBox` Controls in my User Control like so:

```
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control childc in c.Controls)
        {
            if (childc is TextBox)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I need to loop the selected `ListView` row column headers. If their column header matches TextBox.Tag then display the column value in their respected TextBox.

The final code would look something like this:

```
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control childc in c.Controls)
        {

          // Needs another loop for the selected ListView Row

            if (childc is TextBox && ColumnHeader == childc.Tag)
            {
               // Display Values
            }
        }
    }
```

So then my question would be: How can I loop through the selected `ListView` Row and each column header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping over your `ColumnHeaders`  is simply done like this:

```
foreach(  ColumnHeader  lvch  in listView1.Columns)
{
    if (lvch.Text == textBox.Tag) ; // either check on the header text..
    if (lvch.Name == textBox.Tag) ; // or on its Name..
    if (lvch.Tag  == textBox.Tag) ; // or even on its Tag
}
```

However the way you loop over your `TextBoxes` is not exactly nice even if it works. I suggest that you add each of the participating `TextBoxes` into a `List<TextBox>`. Yes, that means to add 40 items, but you can use `AddRange` maybe like this:

To fill a list myBoxes:

```
List<TextBox> myBoxes = new List<TextBox>()

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //..
    myBoxes.AddRange(new[] {textBox1, textBox2, textBox3});
}
```

Or, if you really want to avoid the `AddRange`and also stay dynamic, you can also write a tiny recursion..:

```
private void CollectTBs(Control ctl, List<TextBox> myBoxes)
{
    if (ctl is TextBox) myBoxes.Add(ctl as TextBox);
    foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls) CollectTBs(c, myBoxes);
}
```

Now your final loop is slim and fast:

```
foreach(  ColumnHeader  lvch  in listView1.Columns)
{
    foreach (TextBox textBox in myBoxes)
        if (lvch.Tag == textBox.Tag)  // pick you comparison!
            textBox.Text = lvch.Text;
}
```

Update:  since you actually want the `SubItem` values the solution could look like this:

```
ListViewItem lvi = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsu in  lvi.SubItems)
    foreach (TextBox textBox in myBoxes)
       if (lvsu.Tag == textBox.Tag)  textBox.Text = lvsu.Text;
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think about that. I don't know why I didn't see that. haha. What I meant to say is I need to get the values out of the selected row, not the headers.

Comment: Well, I have updated the answer anyway ;-) Note the way I loop over the subitems: The ListViewSubItem  type has to be qualified!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for greeting all the values.

```cs
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items) 
{               
    SaveFile.WriteLine(lvi.Text + "_" + lvi.SubItems[1].Text);
}
```